# Changing the queryKey argument in bootstrap autocomplete

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, autocomplete, tastypie

I am using [bootstrap autocomplete](https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to fetch data from [django-tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The problem that I am facing is that bootstrap autocomplete uses a parameter `q`, while tastypie has all the regular django options. I could like to change `q` to `name__contains` so that the ajax query can work with the api exported with tastipie.

How can I do it? I am not able to find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question is pretty old but I am doing this like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.basicAutoComplete').autoComplete({
        resolver: 'custom',
        events: {
            search: function (qry, callback) {
                $.ajax(
                    'https://URL.JSON', {
                        data: {
                            'yourParameter[ABC]': qry
                        }
                    }
                ).done(function (res) {
                    callback(res.results)
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

My parameter would be `yourParameter[ABC]` and qry is the value from my input.

Input is...

```
    <input data-url="https://URL.JSON" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="" class="form-control basicAutoComplete">
```